# No endpoint could be found for - Camel Http Integration

Tags: apache-camel

I'm trying to run a simple test with Apache Camel:

```
   from("http://localhost:61554/api/v1/MyController/my-endpoint")
            .to("direct:a")
            .log("$({body}");
```

I'm getting the following error:  "No endpoint could be found for: http://localhost:61554/api/v1/MyController/my-endpoint, please check your classpath contains the needed Camel component jar"

I'm very new to Camel and Java.  Can someone please tell me why this error is coming up?  Should I be using  from("direct:x")... ?  If, so where do I map my "direct" endpoints to concrete ones?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have "camel http" dependency in POM file, if not add the same

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the http component as consumer (eg in from) - its a http client for calling HTTP servers (so its a producer, eg to).

Instead to have HTTP as consumer you can use camel-servlet, camel-jetty, camel-undertow, etc.

Comment: I got some error when upgrade 3.1 to .3.2 in my custom component.I can access endpoint definition from application context but producer doesnt see it.I tried to set producer directly producerTemplate.setDefaultEndpoint(ingRestClientEndpoint); still same issue.camelContext.getRestConfiguration("servlet",true); I remove from code when I upgrade 3.2 but should I put anything else